# How many outlets can be wired to the load side of a GFCI?

Tags: electrical, gfci

I have read a few places that the longer the wire is and the more numerous the outlets hooked up to the load side of a GFCI, the lower the threshold for tripping becomes as a result of leakage current, which may become a problem from frequent tripping. However, I cannot find any hard numbers on the limitations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the specs with the GFCI manufacturer.

Square D for example has a few requirements for GFCI breakers.

1. Must be located no more than 250 ft. (76 m) from the load being served.
2. UL requires that
   GFCIs must be operational at 85% of the rated voltage

Other than that, there is no restriction per se for how many outlets can be on one branch circuit,  residential speaking that is.

Comment: The GFCI's that I have are EATON Arrow Harts. I looked through the manual that they came with but can't couldn't find any details in there.  I looked them up online but couldn't find anything there either. I guess another manufacturers specifications should work, so I'll just go with the specifications you have listed. Is there any restriction on the number of outlets  beyond the standard 13 outlets for a 20 amp circuit and 10 outlets for a 15 amp circuit ?

Comment: Other Codes may exist,  but the NEC in general doesn't have a maximum number of receptacles for residential applications.

Comment: Doing the math: `VoltageDrop = 2 * 250' * 20A * 0.00193 ohms/ft.`  `VD = 19.3 V` Which would put it at ~84% of 120 volts.

Comment: Isn't 84% * 120 = 100.8 volts a bit too low to be usable? Also, isn't 12 gauge copper closer to 0.0016 ohms/ft?